# What globals are available in template expressions?

Tags: vue.js

I'm reading the Vue.js guide, and I've come across the statement.

> Template expressions are sandboxed and only have access to a whitelist
>   of globals such as `Math` and `Date`. You should not attempt to access
>   user defined globals in template expressions.

What are *all* the globals available in templates? 
That is, what is the content of the whitelist, exhaustively?

Comment: For reference, the source file & line where this can be found is: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/v2.6.10/src/core/instance/proxy.js#L9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue.js defines the whitelist of globals in the [core/instance/proxy.js](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/v2.6.10/src/core/instance/proxy.js#L9) file:

```
//...

  const allowedGlobals = makeMap(
    'Infinity,undefined,NaN,isFinite,isNaN,' +
    'parseFloat,parseInt,decodeURI,decodeURIComponent,encodeURI,encodeURIComponent,' +
    'Math,Number,Date,Array,Object,Boolean,String,RegExp,Map,Set,JSON,Intl,' +
    'require' // for Webpack/Browserify
  )

// ...
```

When Vue compiles the template, the string interpolations are processed, and if you reference a global that is not whitelisted, you will have a warning on Development.

If you are curious about how templates are compiled to render functions, look through the [template explorer](https://template-explorer.vuejs.org/).

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood from [source code](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/v2.6.10/src/core/instance/proxy.js#L9) globals are declared in a variable and make it available via a proxy between vm instance and template :

```
  const allowedGlobals = makeMap(
    'Infinity,undefined,NaN,isFinite,isNaN,' +
    'parseFloat,parseInt,decodeURI,decodeURIComponent,encodeURI,encodeURIComponent,' +
    'Math,Number,Date,Array,Object,Boolean,String,RegExp,Map,Set,JSON,Intl,' +
    'require' // for Webpack/Browserify
  )
```

So gobals available in template are :

- Infinity
- undefined
- NaN
- isFinite
- isNaN
- parseFloat
- parseInt
- decodeURI
- decodeURIComponent
- encodeURI
- encodeURIComponent
- Math
- Number
- Date
- Array
- Object
- Boolean
- String
- RegExp
- Map
- Set
- JSON
- Intl
- require

If you try to put in your template a reference that is not whitelisted or not in your vm instance then you will have this warning :

```
  Property or method "${key}" is not defined on the instance but
  referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive
  either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
  initializing the property.
```